# Why can we not establish the irrationality of Catalan's constant the same way as $\zeta(3)$?

Tags: irrational-numbers, riemann-zeta, irrationality-measure

One of the main ingredients in Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ is the existence of the fast-converging series:

$$
{\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\zeta (3)&={\frac {5}{2}}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{{\binom {2k}{k}}k^{3}}}\end{aligned}}}.
$$

Despite numerous attempts, no similar expressions were found for other values of the Riemann $\zeta$-function at positive odd integers.

For Catalan's constant, however, we **do** have such an expression, namely:

$${\displaystyle G={\frac {\pi }{8}}\log \left(2+{\sqrt {3}}\right)+{\frac {3}{8}}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{(2n+1)^{2}{\binom {2n}{n}}}}.}$$

Why is this not sufficient for applying an Apéry-like method for proving its irrationality?

Comment: Having such an expression is by no means the same as irrationality. It is not clear how to adapt Apery's proof.

Comment: Even if such expression were sufficient to prove irrationality, it would only prove it for the series. Then the question of the irrationality of the sum of the series *and* $\frac{\pi}{8}\log(2+\sqrt{3})$ would still be another question I think

Comment: @Giafazio If could be that the right hand term is a linear combination of one or more of the constants in the left hand term though

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the central binomial series I've discovered in arXiv paper  https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3139, namely $$G = -\,\frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^n \, \frac{(3n-1)\,8^n}{(2n+1)^3 \, \binom{2n}{n}^3}}$$, can be useful for you. There in that paper I've shown that the convergence rate of my series is better than that you mentioned above!  Regards, Fabio

Comment: That's interesting, thanks